# how to define code shortcut in webstorm IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

Is it possible to define "shortcuts" to use with Webstorm something like below?
Example: pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> would then insert at cursor position a "`console.log()`"

Comment: Why not create and use Live Template directly (where `cl[TAB]`(for example) would insert such snippet)? https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm

Comment: That's exactly what i needed! Did not know they exist. Thank you

Comment: @LazyOne If you add this as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use existing [Live Templates](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm) functionality (code snippets) to have `cl[TAB]` (for example) to be expanded into `console.log(CURSOR_HERE);`

If you need actual dedicated keyboard shortcut ... then I may only suggest to record a macro that types such text and assign shortcut to it.

Answer (score 1):

In Webstorm:
1.Type `Ctrl+Alt+S`. You are in preferences.

2.Type `Live Templates`

3.Type `+`

Create new group. Then create template there:

`console.log($END$)`

and chose any abrevation you want `cl` for example

Comment: I also had to add "Applicable in" and select "Everywhere" or whatever language you want to use it for. This option is located at the bottom of the window.